# searching the exchange account

Tags: blockchain, meta-transactions

At the end of February I did a transfer of my Etherums. I sent them from my Ledger hard wallet to Metamask. Apparently they never ended up there. I do have the wallet addresses. How can I find the exchange account with these addresses?

Comment: Hi there. So you sent the ETH from your Ledger wallet to _your_ Metamask account? How did you create the Metamask account? Do you have the transaction ID for the transfer?

Comment: I already had a Metamask account when I made the Ledger> Metamask transactionYes I have the transaction ID, but it's different as my Metamask account.

Comment: So you sent the ETH to your Metamask account, but it went to a different address? Have you checked that your entered the Metamask address correctly when you made the transfer?

Comment: That is, of course, a good question. The transaction happened on February 28. I no longer remember that naturally. I made the transfer two separate times in a row. Apparently every time to a different address. At no point have I been suspicious. The intention was to stake the etherums at Ankr. But I don't find them there either. Can I find them with the transaction address where they are?